# Why does the cursor not move forward on sending space (' ') with the sendkeys.js plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

On sending space (' ') while using the sendkeys.js plugin, the cursor does not move forward, though when the next character is inserted (using sendkeys) a space appears before it.

I can't figure out by debugging why this is happening?

Comment: can you add a fiddle or plunkr ?

Comment: Just realized that this is only the case with content-editable divs. It is working fine with text boxes. Would be sharing a fiddle in a short while.

Comment: It is working correctly in fiddles also. My issue seems to be a app specific one. :/  http://jsfiddle.net/DxER9/483/